# Append list to a row

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, openpyxl

I have List Called `my_list` have series of No I want add that no to a excel's perticuler row

1. I want list's No start from `E2` to `len(my_list)`
2. And row is a single and start from E2 to AH2
3. elements will place in E2 to AH2 likewise image

[Click On Here To see Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnvmo.png)

```
wb = load_workbook("Myworkbook.xlsx")
ws = wb.active
my_list=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31]

for rw in ws['E2:AH2']:
    for cell in rw:
        for c in my_list:
            cell.value = c


wb.save('Myworkbook.xlsx')
```

But In this way I just get last element of `list` like in image it gives only 31 but i want 1 to 31
in range and append in particularly in that single row

[Click On Here To See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2kIJ.png)

Comment: As you iterate over my_list you assign different values to the same cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your last loop (over my_list) goes through the entire list, up to 31, for each cell of your row. That's why you end up with the last value in every cell. You have nested this loop too deep.

What you actually want is go through each cell and value at the same time. Simplest way to achieve that is to zip both lists together and loop over that.

```py
wb = load_workbook("Myworkbook.xlsx")
ws = wb.active
my_list=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31]

for rw in ws['E2:AH2']:
    for cell, c in zip(rw, my_list):
        cell.value = c


wb.save('Myworkbook.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case for each `cell` the `my_list` is traversed to the **end** (by innermost `for` loop) having each cell assigned with last value, while it's needed to map cells and `my_list` values pairwise:

To fix that you can apply the following:

```
for row in ws['E2:AH2']:
    for i, cell in enumerate(row):
        cell.value = my_list[i]
```